# Bitbucket загрузить измененные файлы из главного репозитория

Tags: git, bitbucket

Подскажите, как загрузить файлы, которые обновились в главном репозитории на Битбакете, при этом не затирая мои изменения, которые я сделал локально?

Comment: за'`commit`'ить/за'`stash`'ить локальные изменения и сделать `git pull`.

Comment: @Fat-Zer а как потом применить за'shash'ное?

Comment: `git stash pop`

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а как посмотреть засташенное? Оформляйте ответ

Comment: `git stash show`, по желанию можно добавить индекс из `git stash list` и, например, `-p`... по поводу ответа — может попозже, если не забуду...

Comment: `git fetch` вытащит всё с удалённого репозитория не изменяя локальные файлы

Comment: @IvanVovk, в общем то почти всё уже болей менее расписано *vmchar*'ом... не вижу особого смысла переписывать ещё раз

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подытоживая все, что обозначено в комментариях, плюс еще одно возможное решение.

Все зависит от того, что вы хотите сделать со своими локальными изменениями и какое состояние хотите получить в локальном репозитории, есть несколько вариантов:

1. [git fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) - команда, которая загрузит информацию обо всех коммитах в ветке в ваш локальный репозиторий, но не будет сливать его с вашей локальной версией ветки, независимо от того, есть ли какие-то локальные изменения у вас или нет. Ваши текущие наработки будут в сохранности, даже если они не закоммичены, информация с удаленного репозитория будет получена локально, но не будет наложена на текущее состояние репозитория.

   Иногда у разработчиков возникает вопрос, в чем разница между `git fetch` и `git pull`. Про `git pull` можно сказать, что сначала эта команда сделает `git fetch`, а затем накатит полученные изменения на текущее состояние ветки вашего локального репозитория (`git merge` локальной и удаленной ветки) при этом могут возникнуть конфликты, которые не позволят накатить изменения из удаленного репозитория на локальный. В таком случае вся полученная информация останется у вас локально (как будто отработал просто `git fetch`), и вы получите сообщение о конфликте, и созданный, но не отправленный merge-commit с этими конфликтами.
2. [git stash](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5) - команда, которая позволяет "прятать" незакоммиченные изменения, не создавая коммит в истории. Сама по себе может использоваться с параметрами: `git stash apply` - накатит ранее спрятанные изменения, но не удалит их из прятки `git stash push`  - отправит в прятку ваши изменения, `git stash pop` - похоже на apply, но после накатывания спрятанных изменений удалит их из прятки. Кроме того, вы можете удалить все или выбранные вами спрятанные изменения. Подробнее, можно почитать [здесь](https://mijingo.com/blog/saving-changes-with-git-stash) и [здесь](https://ru.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-stash).
3. Решение через git pull. Тут все наиболее наглядно. Создаете ветку от текущей, куда заливаете все свои незакоммиченные изменения. Делаете `git pull` исходной ветки. Далее в зависимости от того, что вам нужно. Можете сделать merge определенных коммитов из свежих изменений, либо просто смотрите нужные вам изменения, либо делаете полный merge и правите конфликты, продолжая работу в основной ветке. При этом вы можете создать только локальную ветку для ваших незакоммиченных изменений и после megre продолжить работать в исходной ветке, тем самым не засоряя историю.

Comment: ссылки на «здесь» битые...